How can I remove nulls in the process of unpivoting a polars dataframe?
I have a large polars dataframe that I need to unpivot. This dataframe contains lots of null values (at least half). I want to drop the nulls while unpivoting the dataframe. I already tried to unpivot the dataframe first and then filter it with drop_nulls() or similar approaches. However, this is too memory-intensive (on a machine with about 1TB RAM).
Is there any way in which I can filter the dataset already during the process of unpivot?
Any help is appreciated!
Sample data.
# in reality, this dataset has about 160k rows and columns 
# (square matrix), and is about 100GB
df = {
    "A": [None, 2, 3],
    "B": [None, None, 2],
    "C": [None, None, None], 
    "names": ["A", "B", "C"]
}
df = pl.DataFrame(df)

df.unpivot(index = "names", variable_name = "names_2", value_name = "distance")

Output.
shape: (9, 3)
┌───────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ names ┆ names_2 ┆ distance │
│ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---      │
│ str   ┆ str     ┆ i64      │
╞═══════╪═════════╪══════════╡
│ A     ┆ A       ┆ null     │
│ B     ┆ A       ┆ null     │
│ C     ┆ A       ┆ null     │
│ A     ┆ B       ┆ 2        │
│ B     ┆ B       ┆ null     │
│ C     ┆ B       ┆ null     │
│ A     ┆ C       ┆ 3        │
│ B     ┆ C       ┆ 2        │
│ C     ┆ C       ┆ null     │
└───────┴─────────┴──────────┘

This could then be filtered (e.g. using df = df.drop_nulls()), but I would like to get this desired result directly from the unpivot.
Expected output.
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ names ┆ names_2 ┆ distance │
│ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---      │
│ str   ┆ str     ┆ i64      │
╞═══════╪═════════╪══════════╡
│ A     ┆ B       ┆ 2        │
│ A     ┆ C       ┆ 3        │
│ B     ┆ C       ┆ 2        │
└───────┴─────────┴──────────┘


It's not fully clear what do you mean by "dataset has about 160k rows and column". Could you clarify how many columns the DataFrame has?

I've modified the question accordingly. It's a square matrix, so it has an equal number of rows and columns. I just want to emphasize that the dataset is large, that's why the first-melting-then-filtering approach doesn't work

Have you tried using a LazyFrame instead?

What would the advantage of a LazyFrame implementation be in this context? My understanding is that they aren't evaluated immediately, but eventually when it's executed it'll still have to perform the melt and drop_nulls sequentially, no?

Very likely you can make the operation more efficient in runtime and memory consumption by using pl.LazyFrames and polars' streaming engine.
By using pl.LazyFrames, the melt / unpivot and filter / drop_nulls won't be operations eagerly, but first aggregated into a query plan. When collecting the lazy DataFrame (i.e. materialising it into a pl.DataFrame), the query plan can be optimised, taking into account subsequent operations.
Streaming will enable the processing to not done all-at-once, but executed in batches, ensuring that the processed batches don't grow larger-than-memory.
(
    df
    # convert to pl.LazyFrame
    .lazy()
    # create query plan
    .unpivot(
        index="names",
        variable_name="names_2",
        value_name="distance"
    )
    .drop_nulls()
    # collect pl.LazyFrame while using streaming engine
    .collect(streaming=True)
)

Note. Tentative tests on my machine give large improvements in runtime and memory consumptions.

Thank you very much, this sounds perfect! I haven't tested it substantially yet, but I will accept the answer for now and answer a new one if I have more specific problems.

@NilsR To further mitigate memory constrains, you can do scan_parquet (hopefully that's the source format) instead of df.lazy() and instead of .collect(streaming=True) do sink_parquet(new_path)

You can create an iterable of dataframes, which you can later concat or process separately
pl.concat(
    df.filter(pl.col(c).is_not_null()).select(
        names = pl.lit(c),
        names_2 = pl.col.names,
        distance = pl.col(c)
    ) for c in df.schema.keys() if c != "names"
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ names ┆ names_2 ┆ distance │
│ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---      │
│ str   ┆ str     ┆ i64      │
╞═══════╪═════════╪══════════╡
│ A     ┆ B       ┆ 2        │
│ A     ┆ C       ┆ 3        │
│ B     ┆ C       ┆ 2        │
└───────┴─────────┴──────────┘


Thank you for a good suggestion! It seems to work in principle, however it looks like it's much much slower than the melt function, which is a problem :/ Any idea how to make this more efficient?
